# Empty string SQL not working

Tags: sql, database, string, postgresql, text

I have a table of grades where each grade cannot be NULL. Each grade is a text so I'm guessing if the column is empty then it is an empty string, ' '. I want to select the columns where the grade is empty. I'm doing:

```
SELECT student FROM simulated_records WEHRE grade = ' ';
```

but this is not working and I dont understand why. Is there a right way of doing it? I'm new to SQL.

Comment: It's bad idea to store "empty" grades. Use NULL if the grade is unknown/not set.

Comment: The "where" statement in your SQL query is misspelled.

Comment: `' '` is not an "empty" string, it's a string with one single (space) character An empty string is `''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will address two scenarios that could be present in your database table. The first is a "null value" i.e. the value was never set and null values are allowed.   The second is the empty string.

```
SELECT student FROM simulated_records WHERE trim(grade) = '' OR grade IS NULL
```

Comment: Trimming the string will make it work  for both space(s) and empty string: `where trim(both from grade) = '' or grade is null`

Comment: Although this will make things work, I would advise to make your column nullable and update the column to null where it has a blank or empty string. Once done use is null.

Comment: Hi @Rachelle if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: What does this part of the code do? "TRIM(BOTH FROM"

Comment: "BOTH FROM GRADE" are comments to the OP.  In hindsight, these should have not been added directly to the code, but rather a comment on the side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want select columns with empty grade column then why you're looking for " "? There is empty space. Try this

```
SELECT student FROM simulated_records WHERE grade IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

each grade cannot be NULL so no need to check with "grade is NULL" just do

```
SELECT student FROM simulated_records WEHRE TRIM(grade) = '';
```